# ORA-06502 PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I am executing sql script which performs basic DML operations.

But strange thing is I am getting ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error while executing it for ONLY 1st time.
**But surprisingly error doesn't came up when executed for 2nd time.**

Please find error below :

```
07:59:57 SQL> @TEST.sql
-6502ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value errorORA-06512: at "SYS.OWA_UTIL", line354
ORA-06512: at "SYS.OWA_UTIL", line 373
ORA-06512: at "User.TableName", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 594
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
Elapsed: 00:00:02.97
08:00:04 SQL> @TEST.sql
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.05
08:00:07 SQL> exit
```

So when I do sqlplus , error appears for 1st time execution then if I execute 2nd , 3rd time I didn't get any error.

I am doubtful about sqlplus environment setting ? Each time I do sqlplus only for 1st execution I am facing this error.

Have anyone faced same issue OR this is any kind of bug with oracle?

Comment: Such a behaviour happens when a plsql package has initialisation code that fails. Check if there is a package involved that has an error or is used incorrectly.

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller : Thanks. Will check this & will update question if found any.

Comment: Your script appears to be doing more than basic DML. It would help if you included your script - or at least the part that's throwing the error - and the code for "User.TableName", which is presumably a fake name you've edited in for a procedure you are calling from an anonymous block, not a table. As Erich says, this is likely to be to do with initialisation or state or some session context that is being set later in your script (so second run in the same session doesn't see it).

Comment: oracle couldn't manage this issue for long years. I corresponded with Oracle's tecnical staff in a tar related to this when we had version 7. Now we have version 12c in our enterprise, problem still persists.